# R: outer on array in first dimension

Tags: arrays, r

outer in R gives outer product of arrays. For example, for matrix `A` with dimension `c(2, 3)`,

```
A <- matrix(1:6, 2, 3)
B <- outer(A, A, function(x,y) x + y)
```

B has dimension `c(2, 3, 2, 3)`. But can I define a function `myouter` in a concise way to apply `outer` only in the first dimension, to get a matrix `C`?

```
C <- myouter(A, A, function(x,y) sum(x) + sum(y))
```

`C` can be obtained by the following tedious code.

```
C <- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:2) {
    C[i, j] <- sum(A[i, ])+ sum(A[j, ])
  }
}
```

Comment: `outer(rowSums(A), rowSums(A), '+')` ?

Comment: `outer(rowSums(A), rowSums(A), '+')` works in the described example. But if I replace `function(x,y) sum(x) + sum(y)` by a more generic function, for example `cor`, then I will need to define `myouter`.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by first dimension as I don't see what the sum over the rows has to do with an outer product (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product)

Comment: with a more generic function like cor() would you do cor([A[i,]) + cor([A[j,]) ? Why have C only 2 by 2 here and not 2 by 3 ?